# Passing ERB code from rails helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

i want to send this to views,

```
  if !mapped.correct?
    html << "<%= link_to toggle_correct_mapped_path(mapped), class: 'btn btn-success'%>"
  else
    html << "<%= link_to toggle_wrong_mapped_path(mapped), class: 'btn btn-danger'%>"
  end
```

But i literally get this

```
"<%= link_to toggle_correct_mapped_path(mapped), class: 'btn btn-success'%>"
```

Comment: Going to ask the stupid question.  What if you remove the quotation marks in your if statement?

Comment: Yeah had to remove the Quotation mark and the <%=

Answer (score 2):

Fixed.

Had to remove the quotation mark and the <%=. Just,

```
html << link_to(toggle_correct_mapped_path(mapped), class: 'btn btn-success')
```